# compilation error-vb.net not a member error

Tags: vb.net, compiler-errors

i am trying to write some code behind a webpage to send an email onClick of a button.

i have a text box

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSecEmail" runat="server" Width="189px" 
ontextchanged="txtSecEmail_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

i also have a button after that

```
<asp:Button ID="btnUploadFiles" runat="server" Text="Upload Files"      
    Command="Command"
 CommandArgument="CommandArgument"
 runat="server" onclick="btnUploadFiles_Click"  />
```

when i try to load the page i get this error

Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: BC30456: 'txtSecEmail_TextChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.datauploaddatafiles_aspx'.

```
Source Error:


Line 94:             <td>
Line 95:                 &nbsp;&nbsp; EMAIL ADDRESS:
Line 96:                 <asp:TextBox ID="txtSecEmail" runat="server" Width="189px" 
Line 97:                     ontextchanged="txtSecEmail_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
Line 98:             </td>
```

Source File: Y:\Prog\NET\web\ClientCenterNew\datauploaddatafiles.aspx    Line: 96

i dont understand how it is not a member? and why its saying this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is looking for the txtSecEmail_TextChanged method in the codebehind (datauploaddatafiles.aspx.vb).  Put that sub routine in the code behind file and rebuild.

Example:

```
Protected Sub txtSecEmail_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, _
        ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtSecEmail.TextChanged
   'Some Code
End Sub
```

Comment: yes i see that but the txtSecEmail.TextChanged says handles clause requires with events variable defined in the containing type

Comment: You may need to rebuild as it should be defined looking at your .Aspx code.  You can get rid of the Handles txtSecEmail.TextChanged to see that the solution provided will resolve the question you asked.

Comment: yea i have no idea why this is happening...it should be there but isnt

Comment: Sometimes rebuilding the solution helps.  If its still being goofy you can try deleting and re-adding the control in the .Aspx markup.

Comment: haha yea i know, ive done all of that. I gotta ask my senior .net guy just didnt want to because its such a dumb question to ask him but thank you for the ideas i appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you don't have two web pages inadvertently using the same class name which may occur if you have copied a page without changing the class name.
Visual Studio may make your code behind a Partial Class without your knowledge in this case.